# Nuxt 3 testing page with async useFetch, onMounted and Vitest

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm trying to test a Nuxt page, but I'm having a promises issue because mocked fetch works but the page is not mounted

this is the page script:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const { data } = await useAsyncData('project', () => $fetch('/api/path'))

const projects = data.value

const fixedCtaSection = ref(null)
const displayFixed = ref(false)
onMounted(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      displayFixed.value = entry.isIntersecting
    })
  }, { threshold: 0.5 })

  if (fixedCtaSection.value) {
    observer.observe(fixedCtaSection.value)
  }
})
</script>
```

And this is the test:

```js
import { flushPromises, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import type { VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'

import PageIndex from '@/pages/index.vue'

const projects = [{ name: 'proj1' }]
vi.stubGlobal('useAsyncData', () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      data: { value: projects }
    })
  })
})

const observeMock = vi.fn()
const unobserveMock = vi.fn()
const disconnectMock = vi.fn()
const mockIntersectionObserver = vi.fn()

mockIntersectionObserver.mockReturnValue({
  observe: observeMock,
  unobserve: unobserveMock,
  disconnect: disconnectMock
})

window.IntersectionObserver = mockIntersectionObserver

describe('PageIndex', () => {
  describe('PageIndex mounted', () => {
    let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallowMount(PageIndex)
    })

    it('should do', async () => {
      await flushPromises()

      // Here is no mounted. onMounted doesn't run

      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
      expect(observeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(wrapper.vm.$refs.fixedCtaSection)
    })
  })
})
```

Mocked `asyncData` is working but `onMounted` not

I have tested adding the appropriate promises in the mocks. I have also used `flushPromises` and `nextTick` (from wrapper and importing from Vue).

I expect the `onMounted` working on the tests.

Page works with `yarn dev`

Here is and environment with the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-sfvvro?file=tests%2Fpages%2Findex.test.js